# Azure web sites rendering issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, rendering, azure-web-app-service, internet-explorer-11

I have an MVC development which works fine when run locally.  When deployed to an Azure Web Site, I'm seeing the same results (as expected) in Firefox, Chrome, IE8, and others.  When viewed in IE11 (the same browser that I'm using to view the site locally), the layout is all over the place.

It seems that when Azure Web Sites renders the site, the IE11 browser is dropping into "7 (Default)" Document Mode.  Pressing F12 and resetting to Edge gets the rendering back to how it should be.

I'm struggling to work out what is going on in Azure Web Sites that is causing this behaviour.  I'm thinking it's a compatibility setting somewhere and any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks,  Nick.

Comment: can you try adding the following html tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` to your shared layout page. This should force IE to use the latest rendering mode

Comment: Thanks @ahmelsayed, I've tried that and it appears to have fixed it.  Thanks for taking the time.  Thanks also tereško for tidying up my tagging, too.

Comment: Awesome! You can answer your question with what worked for you and accept your own answer to mark the question as answered and help anyone else who might stumble upon a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by @ahmelsayed above, adding the

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

tag has fixed the problem.  Thanks for the support.